# How to build a select in mysql when a "where" column may not be there

Tags: mysql

Working in ColdFusion, I have a MySql query which could apply to any number of tables.  The particular table is stored in a variable called "basetab".   So the query begins as

```
select * from #basetab#
```

I go on to check a particular column:

```
select * from #basetab# 
<cfif basetab Eq 'RepSave'>
    where RepSavArch != 'Y'
</cfif>
```

However, I really need to check a column in any table that is named SomethingArch.  Because I know the basetab, I know what the something is.  So I want to write

```
    select * from #basetab#
    where #prefix#Arch != 'Y'
```

This works.  However, not all the tables have a 'somethingArch' column, so I need not to do this unless 'somethingArch' is there.

Can someone suggest a way to get this done.  I suspect I need a subquery, but don't know how to construct it.

Comment: There are a few things you can do, from adding all #prefix#Arch columns to all the tables with default 'N', using a naming convention with the table names, or, perhaps simplest, to write your code to expect the error when the column isn't there and return an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA's COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html) table. The Information Schema provides meta data about the DBMS such as what tables, columns, indexes, ... exist.

That said, I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm familiar with the Information Schema.  But it sounds like you are suggesting a 2nd query.  If I'm going to do that I might as well query the original table, no?  What I'm trying to do is filter out all records where %Arch is 'Y' provided %Arch exists in the table.